# Saggy around sistered floor joist, how to fix?

Tags: floor, joists, structural

Our house has a single floor joist that has been sistered running down the center of the kitchen. Sounds great except for the part where all the other floor joists have sagged a little bit and now there's a nice ridge in the middle of the floor.

Any recommendations on how to fix the issue?

Comment: "uh oh" - out of interests can you post some photos so people can give advice? OVERALL, the advice should be, contact a reputable qualified contractor & a structural engineer. If it was sistered, perhaps not correctly, but even if so, is it load bearing? Probably is from the description. Was a wall removed? Is there any support jacks? take a photo of the basement surface, perimeter, and the sisitered joists. A photo of the outside of the house with front and side, with explanation of beam location relative can help.

Comment: running out of space on previous comment- continued: What is the year of the house? When did you aquire it, were there any recent rennovations? are there any drainage issues? Has it been freezing there? When did you first notice the issue? ... need cause and effect for best answers.

Comment: @noybman We just bought it this last summer and the issue was present then. The house was built in '72 and the kitchen was remodelled around 2007 from what I can tell. Same layout I imagine (because it's not great). So no walls removed or anything like that. I'll try to get a pic up of the basement underneath!

Answer (score 5):

If the rest of the joists are sagging, the answer is pretty clear. They should be sistered also. Joists sagging badly enough to create a visible depression are in danger of failure (or at least must bounce with comical severity).

Post some photos if you'd like more specific advice.

Comment: His follow up comment really leads me to be more concerned of cause. The house was built in 72, so next question - was it home inspected and what did the inspector say, because he said it existed, so he should already know what needs to be done. If he didn't then who knows! Hell, if no remodeling was done we really need to see the beams and the sistering to see WHY. @Aaron, seriously, get someone qualified in there to look at it, and get us the photos of above/below and around!